# Solandra Sharding: Insider Thoughts

Tags: solandra

Just got started on Solandra and was trying to understand the 2nd 
level details of Solandra sharding.

AFAIK Soalndra creates number of shards configured (as 
"solandra.shards.at.once" property)  where each shard is up to size of 
"solandra.maximum.docs.per.shard".

On the next level it starts 
creating slots inside each shard which are defined by 
"solandra.maximum.docs.per.shard"/"solandra.index.id.reserve.size".

What I understood from the datamodel of SchemaInfo CF that inside a 
particular shard there are slots owned by different physical nodes and 
these is a race happening between nodes to get these slots.

My questions are:

1. Does this mean if I request write on  a particular solr node 
   eg .`....solandra/abc/dataimport?command=full-import` does this request 
   gets distributed to all possible nodes etc. Is this distributed write? 
   Because until that happens how would other nodes be competing for 
   slots inside a particular shard.Ideally the code for writing a doc or 
   set of docs would be getting executed on a single physical JVM.
2. By sharding we tried to write some docs on the single physical node 
   but if it is writing based on the slots which are owned by different 
   physical nodes , what did we actually achieved  as we again need to 
   fetch results from different nodes. I understand that the write 
   throughput is maximized.
3. Can we look into tuning these numbers  -? 
   "`solandra.maximum.docs.per.shard`" , 
   "`solandra.index.id.reserve.size","solandra.shards.at.once`" .
4. If I have just one shard and replication factor as 5 in a single DC 
   6 node setup, I saw that the endpoints of this shard contain 5 
   endpoints as per the Replication Factor.But what happens to the 6th 
   one. I saw through nodetool that the left 6th node doesn't really get 
   any data. If I increase the replication factor to 6 while keeping the 
   cluster on , will this solve the problem and doing repair etc or is 
   there a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Overall the shards.at.once param is used to control parallelism of indexing. the higher that number the more shards are written to at once.  If you set it to one you will always to writing to only one shard.  Normally this should be set to 20% > the number of nodes in the cluster.  so for a four node cluster set it to five.

The higher the reserve size, the less coordination between the nodes is needed. so if you know you have lots of documents to write then raise this.

The higher the docs.per.shard the slower the queries for a given shard will become.  In general this should be 1-5M max.

To answer your points:

1. This will only import from one node. but it will index across many depending on shards at once.
2. I think the question is should you write across all nodes?  Yes.
3. Yes see above.
4. If you increase shards.at.once this will be populated quickly

Comment: Thanks Jake . By now I am pretty in Solnadra also I have another one for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962953/heap-size-of-a-node-in-solandra-cluster

Comment: Jake In the current setup I have 300K docs and shard at once as 1 with max docs again the default ~1m. I have 7 node cluster with RF:7 , so now If I need to distribute data across cassandra cluster I need to reduce the RF to 3 I also will need to decrease the max_doc size since ideally if the total docs are < max_docs it will be written to only 1 physical shard. For reducing RF < 7 I need to redistribute docs to different shards which can only be possible if I reduce the max_docs per shard. I hope i am clear.. whats ur take??